# How to pass a test data table as a parameter in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, testing, parameters, datatables, user-defined-types

I have a stored procedure that I want to test. It uses an already created `User-Defined Table Type ([TicketFields])` which essentialls just has a column called `fieldNames` that holds `nvarchar` field names ('Requestor Name, Requestor Org, etc...). It then creates a temporary table uses the `@keyword` user parameter to search for that keyword within the selected field names. My problem is that when I execute it to test, I can't simply plug in a `datatable` as a parameter.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[bcasp_GetTicketsByKeyword] 
@Keyword nvarchar(150),
@fieldsTable [TicketsFields] READONLY 
AS
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #Ticket(
    [ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [TicketNumber] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Complexity] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [NatureOfInquiry] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SMEResponseDetail] [nvarchar](255) NULL
)

declare @fieldName nvarchar(100)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @initSql nvarchar(max)
set @initSql = 'insert into #Ticket (ID, TicketNumber, Complexity, 
NatureOfInquiry, SMEResponseDetail) SELECT ID, TicketNumber, Complexity, 
CASE
    WHEN Complexity = 1 THEN NatureOfInquiry_T1 
    WHEN Complexity In (2,3,4) THEN NatureOfInquiry_T234
    END, SMEResponseDetail FROM T_Ticket WHERE '
declare @whereClause nvarchar(100)
set @whereClause = ' Like' + '''%' + @Keyword + '%'''
DECLARE tblCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT FieldName from @fieldsTable
OPEN tblCursor
FETCH NEXT from tblCursor into @fieldName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 
set @sql = @initsql + @fieldName + @whereClause
print @sql
EXEC(@sql)

FETCH NEXT from tblCursor into @fieldName
END
Close tblCursor
deallocate tblCursor

select distinct * from #Ticket 
END
```

[image]

Scenario suppose that wanted to search for `keyword` "flood" in the columns with `fieldNames` of "NatureOfInquiry" and "SMEResponseDetail". What could I plug into the below to simulate that and get the correct rows to return?

```
USE [BCATicketManagementTest]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[bcasp_GetTicketsByKeyword]
        @Keyword = N'flood'
        ???
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: Careful, right now what you really have an a big security flaw; specifically `set @whereClause = ' Like' + '''%' + @Keyword + '%'''`. You should not be injecting the values your parameters. Don't use `EXEC (@SQL)`  use `sp_executesql` and parametrise your queries properly.

Comment: There's no reason for dynamic SQL or a cursor. You could use JOIN or CROSS APPLY to use the input table in the query. This stored procedure should probably be a single query

Comment: As for testing, create the table parameter in your test script, fill it and pass it as a parameter, eg `declare @myTable table(ID,....);`

Comment: Also, on a different note, why declare `@keyword` as an `nvarchar(150)` when you're going to truncate it in the above statement and possibly break your code too? If `@keyword` is over 93 characters, the whole thing won't fit in the variable `@whereClause`, and you'll have an unclosed quotation.

Comment: `LIKE '%whatever%'` is going to be *slow* whatever you try though and can't take advantage of indexes and has to scan all rows in a table. If you want to find keywords in tables you should use Full-Text Search indexes and eg [CONTAINSTABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or `FREETEXT`. This way you'll avoid dynamic sql and cursors

Comment: Thanks for the comments; I am new to this and appreciate the suggestions. This SP is being injected into an ASP.Net app and works fine on my local but is having issue once I published and moved to a server.On that note, I have a few questions from the comments: 1) How would I fill the table parameter? Just use something like `INSERT INTO @fieldsTable VALUES('NatureOfInquiry'), ('SMEResponseDetail')? 2) What type should I declare @keyword as? Just maybe shorted it to nvarchar(50)? 3) CONTAINSTABLE and FREETEXT look viable, but could you give me an example in the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
USE [BCATicketManagementTest]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

DECLARE @fieldsTableTest [TicketsFields]
INSERT INTO @fieldsTableTest
SELECT 'CUSTOMERID' UNION ALL SELECT 'MANAGERID' UNION ALL SELECT 'SOME OTHER FIELD'


EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[bcasp_GetTicketsByKeyword]
        @Keyword = N'flood'
        @fieldsTable = @fieldsTableTest
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this task using SSMS.

For more information see [Use Table-Valued Parameters (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Yep, filling the User-Defined Table Type ([TicketFields]) was what I was looking for.